# Limit of entries in Graph API 'home' results

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit, feed

I want to get stream entries from the last x days or weeks in the past. But when I call the news feed via Graph API with parameter 'limit' or 'until', I get entries from the last 48 hours only, no matter how high I define the parameter, also paging to the next pages is not possible, they are empty.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=...&limit=500

It seems that Facebook set up a limit (only in the 'home' feed). Does anybody know if there is a possibility to get more entries from a larger period of time? Or is it possible to get whitelisted from Facebook to receive more entries?

Comment: Have you tried making a FQL query on the "stream" table?

Comment: Question seems clear -- should not have been closed

Answer (score 1):

It seems `/user/home` has been deprecated use `/user/feed` instead

in response to your question the following are available in the graph explorer but i havent been able to find documentation on these. I would do more research on these.

```
/user/feed/?since=<value>
/user/feed/?until=<value>
```